# Adobe BlazeDS Logo

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I am using BlazeDS and I want to visualize it in a presentation. Therefore I am searching fo a BlazeDS logo. I only find 4-5 matches on google images, like this one:
http://www.clemencanaria.co.cc/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/blazeds-logo1.png

Is this the official logo? And if yes, where could I get an image with a better resolution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official logo is here:
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/1114252/blazeds_high_119x125.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to ask directly the product manager - his blog is [here](http://anilchannappa.org/). I made a presentation about BlazeDS using the same logo as you have found, but I never thought if it's the official one or not.